# Communicate with parent's children

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I'm trying to write a GUI with the following structure (only relevant parts):

`Window -> VBox -> HBox -> Frame: Input`

```
               -> ScrolledWindow -> TreeView -> ListStore: Output
```

As soon as the input is received, a list will we computed that is the output. How do I send this list to the ListStore so that it will be displayed? Do I need to drag references of the parent element along in every element? Or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just keep references of your input and your output, then do the following:

- bind a method to your input, that will be called on update or validation,
- in this method, do the treatment needed,
- at the end of this method, update your output, directly using its reference and its internal functions (configure or else).

There maybe a better way to do it (using Var classes?) but that's how I would do it.